# Magento 2: Magento UI is not working properly. After deleting all products

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent

I have Deleted all Products from magento 2 using a SQl Command.

and after that my Magento UI is not Working properly.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

I have tried to with CLI Commands.

php bin/magento cache:Flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:Flush

I have deleted the older `frontend` and compiled

> app\pub\static\frontend

but i can see same UI shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a reindexing.

Please run

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

after that run

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried this many time, it still looks the same. any other Idea how can I check if there is error in core Magento files